# How to fix character encoding in bash (arch linux)

Tags: bash, arch-linux, character-encoding

I have some issues with the encoding of german umlauts in bash.
It mostly is working fine, but when i am typing a invalid command, the error message generated by bash contains strange escape sequences and not the actual characters.

Here is a log, which shows the problem:

```
[root@myhost ~]# mkdir ä
[root@myhost ~]# ä
-bash: $'\303\244': Kommando nicht gefunden.
[root@myhost ~]# ü
-bash: $'\303\274': Kommando nicht gefunden.
[root@myhost ~]# ls
ä  äöü  Projects  tbb
[root@myhost ~]# cat äöü
äüö
[root@myhost ~]# rm ä
rm: Entfernen von „ä“ nicht möglich: Ist ein Verzeichnis
[root@myhost ~]# rmdir ä
[root@myhost ~]# rm äöü
```

the configuration of my `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
LOCALE="de_DE.UTF-8"
DAEMON_LOCALE="no"
HARDWARECLOCK="localtime"
TIMEZONE="Europe/Berlin"
KEYMAP="de-latin1"
CONSOLEFONT=
CONSOLEMAP=
USECOLOR="yes"
```

`/etc/locale.gen` only contains the de_DE locales:

```
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
de_DE ISO-8859-1
de_DE@euro ISO-8859-15
```

`locale` output:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @RomanB: putty, but the problem is the same if use the raw shell locally, so this is a bash issue.

Comment: @smerlin, there is no "the raw shell", do you mean the console, gnome-terminal, urxvt, xterm or another? If you use the console, what happens if you try "export TERM=linux"?

Comment: @Alexander The same: `$ ö
bash: $'\303\266': command not found`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be introduced with bash 4.2. You can report this as a bug to the bash developers.

Comment: I agree. It is spliting up the unicode character into its component bytes, so its Unicode handling is off.